# Entity Framework many-to-many query: navigation property not generated

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have two tables `User` and `UserRole` which are they connected using a link table `UserInRole`

When I generate the entity model, for some reason, the entity `UserInRole` not getting generated. And as you can see from the picture, Entity Framework understood that there is many-to-many relationship between `User` and `UserRole`:

[image]

I need to implement the query like this

```
select ur.Name from [User] as u
inner join UserInRole uir on uir.UserId = u.Id
inner join UserRole ur on ur.Id = uir.UserRoleId
where u.Username = 'magename'
```

I am using generic repository, if navigation property would exists the query would be looking like this:

```
from u in repository.AsQueryable<User>()
join uir in repository.AsQueryable<UserInRole>() on u.Id equals uir.UserId
join ur in repository.AsQueryable<UserRole>() on uir.UserId equals ur.Id
where u.Username == userName
select ur.Name
```

But Entity Framework does not generate `UserInRoles` navigation property and related `UserInRole` entity, so the question what should I do in that situation? Should I remove link between `UserInRole` and `UserRole` to get entity `UserInRole` generated in model or there any way to have the query I described above without any changes in database?

UPDATED

so looks i need to do something like that

```
stirng[] roles = (from u in repository.AsQueryable<User>()
         where u.Username == userName
         select ur.UserRoles.Select(x => x.Name)).ToArray<string>();
```

getting an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'string[]'` any ideas?

Comment: Your problem is: the first select in your UPDATED section will select **a list of users** - whether that contains a single or multiple users isn't relevant, but it's a **list** of users - and from those you select their user roles' names - so you have a list of arrays, basically - that's what the error tells you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You don't need that link table** in your EF model! That's the beauty of EF!!

Check your entity `User` - it has a `UserRoles` navigation property - that's the collection of all roles this user is in.

Check out entity `UserRole`: it has a navigation property `Users` which has all users that are in this role.

With these two multi-valued navigation properties, you can express any of the queries you might want:

- find all users for a given role (find the `UserRole` entity and enumerate its `.Users` property)
- find all roles for a given user (find the `User` and enumerate its `.UserRoles`)

EF and the EDM sort of "hide" that link table from you - you don't really need it when you're expressing your intent in the conceptual model; those link tables are just a "necessary evil" in relational databases since those databases cannot model m:n relationships in any other way.

**Update:** so you seem to want to find a list of all the user roles (their names) that a particular user is in - you can express this something like this:

```
// find the user in your "dbContext" (or via your repository)
var user = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == "magename");

// from the list of UserRoles on that user, select the names only
var userRolesNames = user.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes i saw that properties, and i was thinking that it is some kind of EF magic thing... Trying to figure out the query after that unexpected confusion.