# MVC EF map many-to-many relationship table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

In EF, there is no object that represents the bridge table. But I need to delete/add record to the bridge table so I want to create a class that represents the bridge table

For example:

```
User: userID, name
Group: groupID, name
tblUserGroup: userID, groupID (bridge table)
```

I have the following:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Group { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GroupUser> tblGroupUser { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("Group");
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUser>().HasKey(a => new { a.UserID, a.GroupID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
            .HasMany(u => u.User)
            .WithMany(g => g.Group)

            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("GroupID");
                m.MapRightKey("NetworkUserID");
                m.ToTable("tblGroupUser");
            });
    }
}
```

When I want to use the bridge table

```
context.tblGroupUser...(do sth)
```

The error says

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.GroupUsers'.
```

I think its saying that it doesn't know which table GroupUser map to

But when I add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUser>().ToTable("tblGroupUser");
```

The error change to

```
Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.
```

Now it doesn't allow me to map tblGroupUser 2 times. How can I fix this problem

Other info

```
public class EFGroupkUser
        {
            private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

            public IQueryable<GroupUser> tblGroupUser
            {
                get { return context.tblGroupUser; }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only about add/delete from the junction table, you can simply do it and you don't need to tweak mappings of the model:

```
// ...
User u = db.Users.Find(id);

foreach (var g in u.Groups.ToList())
    db.tblUserGroups.Remove(g);

Collection<GroupUser> gusers = new Collection<GroupUser>();                    
foreach (var item in model.GroupUsers)
{
    tblGroupUser guo = new tblGroupUser();
    guo.UserID = item.UserID;
    guo.GroupID = item.GroupID;

    gusers.Add(guo); 
}

u.Groups = gusers;
db.SaveChanges();
```

You can perform any add/delete you want to a junction table like the above code. If your problem is just that, let the EF does its job by conventions and remove `OnModelCreating`

Answer (score 0):

This question may be `duplicate` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847281/entity-framework-many-to-many-query-navigation-property-not-generated).

If you want to add `a group` to a specific user.

```
var myUser = dbContext.Users.Find(id);
var myGroup= db.Groups.Single(group => group.GroupId == groupId);

myUser.Groups.Add(myGroup);
```

This will `insert` a record to tblUserGroup table.

You can do the `vise versa` too.
If you want to add `a user` to a specific group.

```
myGroup.Users.Add(myUser);
```

But if you really want `tblUserGroup` table to be generated in the edmx, just `add an aditional column` (Let's say IsActive) to the `tblUserGroup` table and then update the edmx. Now you can use the tblUserGroup class.