# Entity framework many to many relationship association not automatically generated

Tags: entity-framework-6, many-to-many, edmx, edmx-designer

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847281/entity-framework-many-to-many-query-navigation-property-not-generated), my problem is quite the opposite, EF is treating the entities as two separate 1 to many relation, so the `User` have many `UserInRole`, and the `Role` also have many `UserInRole` entities, shouldn't EF automatically hide the `UserInRole` table and give a navigation property `Roles` for `User` and `Users` for `Role`. What I want is actually this:

[image: ef model]

Comment: What does your UserInRole table look like?

Comment: It has a primary key, a foreign key userid and a foreign key roleid

Comment: @GertArnold can this be caused by the following: the user had only one role before so it had a foreign key roleid, I removed this key and created the "UserInRole" table and updated the edmx. Because I tried a many to many relationship on another table different form `Role` and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the entity from the edmx and updating changes fixed it, apparently when I updated the model from the database in the edmx designer it kept columns that I removed from the database maybe because it was referenced somewhere else in the project, anyway I deleted the entire entity manually and updated the changes / re-added the missing tables and it did the trick.